# Forwarding logs from F5 Big-ip asm to ELK stack

Tags: assembly, elastic-stack, elk, f5, big-ip

I am new to f5 Bigip asm and elk stack, could you give me any ressources to forward logs from the big ip asm to elk stack ?

I didn’t found any clear ressource for step by step

I need help please !

Im using ubuntu for elastic search